# Server error when sending mail with mailgun on amazon ec2

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mailgun

I have Laravel app with a mailgun account for handling emails.
My app is on amazon instance.

When sending mail on local all works great, but when deploy it gives me 'server error' what makes me think that I should do something on my amazon instance.

Any help with this will be great!

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

The error that I am getting is :

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtgun.org 
[php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not 
known #0]
```

running on Ubuntu

Comment: have you opened 2525 for smtp in VPC security group. check in which security group your instance is place and add an outbound rule for above port. and make sure its a public subnet

Comment: Hey, thanks. When looking at the security group I see that outbound is open to All. type => All Traffic, protocol => All. should be working?

Comment: can you show your detalied error log. it can be laravel logs too.

Comment: I looked at the log, it doesn't look like there is something there...